# DC residual current detection 24 volt DC

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, transistors, mosfet, analog

I am trying to make a DC residual circuit breaker( same as AC 10 mA RCCB) for 24 volt DC load. How can I sense and compare currents in positive and negative terminals and powering circuit off, a difference or leakage observed.

I tried with voltage divider as one resistance in series with +Vcc, the other in series with Gnd  and load connected beween two resistors to sense any drop in leakage curent.I am trying to sense leakage current when human touches in 24 volt DC circuit with working total circuit/ load current of 40 mA. Unfortunately above my approach not working.

Comment: magnetic sensing is probably the best way.

maybe try a closed-loop hall effect sensor, or a flux gate sensor.

Comment: You really haven't written any specifications. For example, a GCFI might be rated for 15 amps but detect a leakage of 10 mA. You mentioned 40 mA, but I don't know if that is the design load or if that's the leakage you want to trip on. (It's probably my fault and I'm just not able to read you well.) You should study GCFIs (just be aware that their cognizance of capacitance as an alternate source of leakage won't apply in the same way with DC.)

Comment: Can you post a schematic of what you tried? Are you aware that your 24 V supply will require an earth connection to work otherwise current won't flow to ground / earth.

Comment: If your working current is 40 mA then use a sense resistor and look for something like 45 to 50 mA to trip the thing you want to trip.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a "pass through" current sensor (using hall effect or fluxgate) This sensor will detect a differential DC current of 3mA , You could get more sensitivity with multiple passes through the aperture.  https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_SE0217_FG.pdf

[image: open aperture fluxgate residual current sensor]

This is a bit expensive, at $100 each, but you can buy similar "open aperture" or "open core"  or "pass through" sensors using hall effect sensors for ~ $20 , I used some about 12yrs ago but can't remember the part number.

Normally to measure earth leakage of a load powered from a DC supply, you would just float the supply and then connect either positive or negative or a resistive centre tap to a ground stake via a 1k resistor, and measure voltage on that.  For buried DC cables, best to put the sense resistor from positive to ground, as this minimises corrosion of the wires.

LEM make some too, e.g. CTSR 0.3P  , just put ten cores through of  each of the feed and return conductors for 30mA full scale output.

[image: LEM CTSR 0.3]

Notes:

1. With all of these residual current sensors you need to have the outgoing and return leads passing through the aperture, and have the same number of turns on each;
2. and your power supply also needs to have one terminal earthed in order to have return current,
3. this takes as back to what I said earlier, just measure the current through (volts across) the earthing resistor,
4. you won't get 40mA of current through a human who touches a 24v wire, maybe if they are standing in a bath of salt water, with wet salty hands.
5. if you put multiple turns through the aperture, this may limit the maximum current you can use , 16g (1.6sqmm) wire has a nominal rating of 16Amps, but if you bunch 20 odd wires together, it will get very hot long before 16Amp.
6. your supply has a large short circuit current, then you may need protective devices to avoid thermally damaging your current sensor during a fault.
7. if a high short circuit current is feasible then check the datasheet of the sensor for it's maximum ampere-turns rating.

Comment: You might edit to point out that the feed and return have to pass through the one current transducer / sensor so that the difference in feed an return is detected. The setup needs to be able to handle the worst-case fault condition when, for example, a short circuit draws high current on the feed and none on the return.

Comment: ... and maybe "put ten **turns** of the feed and the return through" might be more clear than "ten cores".

Comment: @Transistor  made some changes per your suggestions , These sensors typically saturate at overload currents, so should n't be adversely affected by overloads, although you might magnetise nearby bits of steel, or magneto-striction might squash the sensor.

Comment: Thanks. I think they should be OK on quite high over-current as there would have to be an air-gap for the Hall sensor and that would make the core saturation ampere-turns much higher than a closed core. The datasheet is silent in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit below could indicate one direction of pursuit: A differential current sensor using a bridge.

The circuit can be put together using "jellybean" op-amps, and the choice of TL07x and LM32x is not arbitrary. LM324 was chosen for OA2, whose common mode range must include ground. TL074 was chosen for OA1, whose common mode range must include positive supply rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHYgAQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All op-amps are powered from the same 24V supply as the load.

OA1 and OA2 amplify the feed and return current sense voltages from R3 and R4. Their gain is 50x.

These voltages are fed to a bridge consisting of R1-R2, and R11-R14. The differential voltage across that bridge is amplified a further 1000x by OA3 and OA4.

To trim the circuit:

1. Disconnect the load.
2. Set all adjustment potentiometers mid-range.
3. Adjust "Offset Coarse" to bring Leakage voltage as close to zero as possible.
4. Adjust "Offset Fine" to bring Leakage voltage as close to zero again as possible. Note the voltage.
5. Connect a full-scale (40mA) load.
6. Adjust "CMRR Coarse" to bring Leakage voltage as close to zero as possible.
7. Adjust "CMRR Fine" to bring Leakage voltage as close to zero as possible again. Note the voltage.
8. Adjust "Sensitivity" so that the Range voltage is 3-5x larger than the larger of the absolute values of "Leakage" voltage you noted in step 4 and 7.

Now you can close SW1 or SW2 to induce leakage currents. Observe the digital output turn to logical "1" (5V).

The overall voltage gain is 50,000x, and requires some adjustment to the AC bandwidth to keep the thing stable, as well as attention to detail in the layout, shielding, etc. When I put this circuit together, I'll update the schematic to include the decoupling/filtering capacitors I've left out.

Fixed resistors should all be thin film 1% or 0.5%. Potentiometers should be multiturn trimmers.

The design assumes that the load current is largely constant and doesn't change much. If the load current changed by more than a couple percent, a CMRR bootstrap would be necessary for OA1 and OA2. It wouldn't make things any more expensive really, since the parts are all dirt cheap, but it would definitely add to the complexity a bit. No additional trimmable parts would be needed though.

It would be better to use an instrumentation amplifier, but those are more expensive, go out of stock regularly these days, and reduce the fun factor significantly.